# Debugging problem when knitting from r markdown to pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, tinytex

I've downloaded miktex, tinytex and ghostscript and tried changing the path since the problem seems to be in the path. So far nothing has helped me and I would appreciate some help:
This is my error message:

```
    Error: LaTeX failed to compile Uebungsblatt1_MAT183.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Uebungsblatt1_MAT183.log for more info.
    In addition: Warning message:
    In has_crop_tools() : 
    Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
    -> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
    Execution halted
```

Any help or try to troubleshoot would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Kim_S! You may want to include which LaTeX packages your Rmarkdown file imports. Also it might help for you to include some relevant contents of the `Uebungsblatt1_MAT183.log` file for debugging.  You will also want to include your operating system.  Perhaps this post could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197603/how-to-fix-unable-to-find-ghostscript-executable-to-run-checks-on-size-reductio

Comment: The issue is not with ghostscript, etc... You are only getting a warning - not an error message. something is wrong in your rmarkdown, causing your tex file to fail. Without further information, as indicated by @Reilstein, we can't help you further...

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out for myself by now: what I did was that I first uninstalled MikTex and tinytex because they apparently were clashing somehow. Then I reinstalled tinytex - this time typing it directly into the console instead of using the installing tool from R - so I typed everything at a time and executed it. It had me restart R and updated some files then too. Since then it has worked flawlessly. Also, I did the same on my other computer (MacBook) where it didn't work so chances are pretty good that that might solve that same problem for someone else out there. Thanks to everybody who tried helping and improved the question or sent responses.

Answer (score -2):

Which code you tried to compile?
Sometimes this error rise when a letter is missed in the \begin function. If you tried to compile an array, do not forget to use the same letters as rows you need.
Example:

```
$$|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} -x & \text{si }x\le 0\\ x & \text{si }x\ge 0 \end{array}\right.$$
```